# Patterns: High cohesion pattern

Tags: design-patterns

Isn't there a Design Pattern who describes how to high cohesion?

I need some guidance on how and when my classes should be split up in more classes so i get some good high cohesioned classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximising cohesion is one of the principles of good software design.  Design patterns are derived from those principles.  So a pattern like MVC may lead to a code base with a degree of cohesion (or at least a separation of concerns).

But High Cohesion is not a design pattern as such.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe cohesion to be related to design patterns. The best way to determine when a class needs work in regards to cohesion is to use a tool to calculate complexity such as the cyclomatic complexity which as far as I know Visual Studio for example is capable of doing.

Comment: as well as external static analysis tool (also good for other factors): CCCC